# why i can see ipv6 socket with ipv6 stack disable?

Tags: linux, debian, ipv6, netstat

I try to disable complety ipv6 on a Linux Debian 7 (wheezy)
However , things escape me. 
In my case, i test with grafana process (I have same issue with munin, rpcbind etc)

**Method 1 : with sysctl**

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then, i reload config : `sysctl -p`

No registration ipv6 in /etc/hosts

After reboot process grafana, i always see, with netstat, that grafana listen ipv6 socket.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      116        23952       4022/grafana-server
```

Reboot server : reboot the server does not improve things

**Method 2 : disable ipv6 at kernel startup**

Add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"` in /etc/default/grub
Gen new conf : update-grub2

Reboot server : reboot the server does not improve things, i can see a listen ipv6 with netstat :

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      116        23952       4022/grafana-server
```

I have test

How it's possible to bind ipv6 socket if the stack is disable ? Display issues ?
Anyone can explain me this behaviour ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry

Comment: Yeah, no worries. You may get an answer here anyway ;-). (You won't get any friends by post Q to multiple sites.  Also review ipv6 Qs at another Stackexchange site : `http://serverFault.com`. Good Q, but just not appropriate here (IHMO). Good luck.